# Rapidminer R-Extension: Cannot load native library jri.dll

Tags: r, rapidminer, rjava

I am not sure, if this is the right forum for my issue. Please let me know if not and will try it in another one.

Since it seems to be amazing extension, I am trying to run Rapid Miner's R-Extension. Without any success for over a day now. I don't know how to help myself anymore, that's why I decided to write this post.

After starting Rapid Miner I get the error message:

Could not load native library.

R Extension could not be initialized. Error while loading native R library. Please check PATH,R_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables settings.

Reason: 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries'

---

For helping you guys helping me: In the following some info, which might be useful.

**System Info**

```
OS:Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1 64 bit

Rapidminer-version: 5.2.008 64 bit

rapidminer.r.native lib: 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll 

R-Version: 
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
[...]
version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
nickname       Good Sport  

Java version: 
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode) 

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 

R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1 

PATH (part): 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64; C:\Windows\System32; 
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin; 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\server; 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64; 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64
```

**After starting Rapid Miner (console): Part of console output**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
28.08.2013 12:34:48 com.rapidminer.PluginInitR initPlugin
INFO: Trying to load R Library...

28.08.2013 12:34:48 org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine [clinit]
INFO: Creating Connection to R...

28.08.2013 12:34:48 org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine loadLibrary
INFO: Trying to loaded R library from C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll

28.08.2013 12:34:48 org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine loadLibrary
INFO: Engine ID: class org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine ClassLoader:PluginClassLoader ([file:/C:/Users/<...>/.RapidMiner5/managed/rmx_r-5.3.0.jar])

28.08.2013 12:34:48 com.rapidminer.tools.I18N getMessage
WARNING: Missing I18N key: r.could_not_load_native_lib

28.08.2013 12:34:48 com.rapidminer.PluginInitR loadNativeLibrary
SEVERE: r.could_not_load_native_lib
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
*Exception-Stacktrace*

28.08.2013 12:34:48 com.rapidminer.PluginInitR initPlugin
SEVERE: Failed to load R library! Check your R and rJava installation and PATH,R_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
*Exception Stacktrace*
```

**Checking Measure for …\x64\jri.dll**

Checked dependencies of …\x64\jri.dll using Dependency Walker.

Result: Delay-load module warning for module c:\windows\system32\IEFRAME.DLL.

Message: *Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.*

! But: It is possible to load rJava (version: rJava_0.9-4) into a R-workspace. Tried out with RStudio.

---

That's it! I don't know, what to do anymore to get out of this situation. As you can see, I read all posts in *stackoverflow* with the same issue. But nothing helped so far. Is there anything I did not consider?

I appreciate each help very much. If there any things you need to know for further steps please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Rudi

Answer (score 0):

If you change JAVA_HOME so that it points to the Java run time environment, does that help?

In other words, put /jre at the end.

regards

Andrew